# how i can know the uptime on battery

Tags: 14.04, battery, uptime

is there a way I can know how much time the laptop is up on battery  , i know there is the **uptime** -but it Tell how long the system has been running both on AC and battery

Answer (score 0):

```
Power Statistics
```

is what you are looking for.  Select 'Laptop battery' and go to 'history' select 'Time to empty on the 'Graph type' dropdown, you can also find a lot of other useful info in power statistics.